# MySQL query finds rows but returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a 2-column table which I create like this (each user has a table for himself):

```php
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $user_name (
          driver TINYTEXT NOT NULL, 
          reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        )";
```

I have (manually, using phpMyAdmin) inserted data into one such a table. reg_date was set at current time and some random string (numerical, say 01234) was inserted.

I try accessing the rows like this:

```php
$mysql_qry2 = "SELECT * FROM $username";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry2);
$ans = "";

if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
        $ans = $ans . $row["driver"];
        $ans = $ans . " ";
        $x = $row["driver"];
        echo "$x";
        echo "a";
    }
    $ans = $ans . "asd";
    echo "$ans";
} else {
    echo "b";
}
```

edit: after fixing my mistaken variable name, the "SELECT *" query is returning zero rows despite 3 rows of data being there.

Comment: you are using wrong variable name. change if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) to if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)

Comment: thanks! I fixed that and the echo issue, but the problem is that it shows 0 rows in num_rows despite 3 rows being there (Im checking on it with phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Your code looks working. https://phpize.online/?phpses=3d12844d1550998155c3936aefb08204&sqlses=5f09cce2e78f12aa0a667661c89ff0e4&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80 Please check where you set `$username` value

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Creating a table per user is going to create a whole mountain of problems for you. Consider creating one table with a `user_id` column to differentiate data. This can be optimized with table partitioning if necessary.

Comment: You also inject `$username` in those queries with *zero escaping* meaning if you had a user named `DROP` or, worse, `;DROP TABLE ...`  you're in for a world of hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You checked count of wrong variable `mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0`.

```
    $mysql_qry2 = "SELECT * FROM $username";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry2);
    $ans = "";

   if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
            $ans = $ans . $row["driver"];
            echo "$ans";
            echo "a";
      }
    } else {
      echo "b";
    }
```

Comment: thanks! I did forget to add a "2" when I was renaming the variables, but the main problem still insists, my select * query is returning 0 results despite 3 rows being in the table :(